# Как преобразовать многомерный массив с двумя скобками в одномерный?

Tags: python, массивы, list, numpy, список

Как преобразовать такой массив:

```
array([[40.,40.,20.,-20.,30.,-40.,]])
```

в обычный:

```
[40,40,20,-20,30,-40]
```

Comment: не уверен что это numpy.array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```
a = np.array([[40.,40.,20.,-20.,30.,-40.,]])
res = a.ravel().tolist()
```

результат:

```
In [37]: res
Out[37]: [40.0, 40.0, 20.0, -20.0, 30.0, -40.0]
```